# Use WhatsApp for one-way communication to a group

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am a teacher. All my students are using WhatsApp. I want to create a group for my students, and hide the group members to see others' contact details except my contact details.

Also I can only post the messages and others will not post in that group. It will be one way communication for their assignments and quizzes.

Is it possible in WhatsApp Messenger?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. It is always a two-way communication.

Comment: It is not possible. But you can use broadcasts as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a group this might not be possible. However, you can create a Broadcast list - in this way you can send a message in a shot to all participants and they will not be able to see the other members

On WhatsApp click on the overflow button (3 dots) and chose New Broadcast

Hope this helps